# What is the font used in Evangelion's intro screen?

Tags: font-identification, serif

what's the font used in the eye-catch scene?

[image: eyecatch]

Some suggested that it is "マティス EB" http://fontworks.co.jp/font/classic/matisse/EB.html#cont02

Also, what's the font used in the following covers?

[image: dvd cover]
[image: LD cover]

Comment: @Yisela There are quite a few fonts used in the series, e.g. http://forum.evageeks.org/thread/392/Fonts-and-Typography-of-Evangelion/#postrow_9    Therefore I think the title can benefit by being more specific.

Comment: Yes! But the reason of the downvote might have been because font identification questions are a little frown upon here - as they usually have no value for others. That's why I changed it. Let me re-add some details so it's both specific but google-able :)

Comment: It looks like you're correct in thinking the font is Matisse EB by Fontworks. That's what the creators say. [Reference](http://route2015.otakumode.com/interview/01/2/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It could be [Times New Roman Condensed Bold](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/mti/times-new-roman/), a bit modified maybe.

//EDIT:
It actually is Times New Roman Condendsed Bold – with a horizontal scale of 79%.
I compared the font not with the picture you posted (because the quality is so bad), but the Cover of the *Neon Genesis Evangelion: S² Works*. 
The A and the G is slightliy different, because I have the Monotype-verison of Times New Roman, if you try the Linotype-version it should fit.

[image: Font comparison: S² Works-Cover and Times New Roman Condensed Bold]

Comment: Take a look at how the serifs are tapered on Times New Roman as opposed to the provided eye-catch, especially in the capital E. This album cover is _probably_ TNR, but I don't think that the eye-catch is. The eye-catch A is also cut off at the top.

Comment: After some research I think you are right! The eye-catch is the only exception. The LD/DVD covers uses TNR as you said.

Comment: I think you're right. It's a mangled version of TNR. re: protractor's observation--and if you look at how low the lower corner of the 'N' drops below the baseline--I believe the artist also added a stroke to the characters that in turn fattens and smooths out the serifs.

Comment: There are so many versions of the TNR, it's been out there since the 1930s, I guess that's also why the _A_ doesn't fit. And I think that's also the reason why the eye-catch is a bit different, because it's much older than most LD/DVD-covers.
You get the serifs from the eye-catch when you add an outline-stroke, like @DA01 mentioned, also the outer-glow intensifies this effect.

Comment: I think the E is really the biggest mismatch. The A, V, and N are just cut off at the ends. The eye-catch E is evenly balanced, while the TNR E is larger on the bottom and the center line is closer to the top.

Answer (score 1):

I work on photoshop, so this my customization.
They use Arial for the episode's name and the episode's number.
[image]

and this is my re-create version. Just add some effect to the text.
[image]

Answer (score -2):

The font is [Bodoni](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/bitstream/atf-bodoni/). Maybe it's an edited font, but it's definitely inspired by the Bodoni font.

Comment: Hi José and welcome to GD.SE! For font identification questions, we ask that answers include a screenshot and link to the sample.

Comment: Sorry but it's definitely not bodoni - look at the serifs and the G, definitely not the same.